# Code has different performance depending on which CPU cores it's run on

Tags: c++, concurrency, x86-64, cpu-architecture, atomic

I'm profiling some code that uses a spinning barrier.

Compiled with:

```
g++-13 barrier.cc -march=native -o barrier -O3 -Wall -std=c++20
```

Run with:

```
taskset -c 0-3 ./barrier
```

This gives 11,338,408 completions/second.

However, if I change the CPU affinity eg. `taskset -c 6-9 ./barrier`, I'm only getting 3,962,992 completions/second.

The code is only "slow" iff I assign at least one core <8 and at least one core >=8.

I'm testing on Ubuntu 22.04, a 16-core AMD 7950X, mitigations are off, SMT disabled. According to the CPU specification, all cores have their own L1/L2 caches and they all share a common a L3 cache. Why does it matter on which cores I run the code?

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

// A barrier that busy waits until all other threads reach the barrier.
template <typename Completion>
class SpinningBarrier {
    int64_t count_;
    std::atomic<int64_t> spaces_ __attribute__((aligned(128)));
    std::atomic<int64_t> generation_ __attribute__((aligned(128)));
    Completion completion_cb_;

    public:
    // Constructs a spinning barrier with |count| participating threads and
    // completion callback |completion_cb|.
    // After all threads reach the barrier, the last thread executes the
    // completion callback. The other threads are blocked until the completion
    // callback returns.
    SpinningBarrier(int64_t count, Completion completion_cb) :
        count_(count), spaces_(count), generation_(0),
        completion_cb_(completion_cb) {}

    void Wait() {
        int64_t my_generation = generation_;
        if (--spaces_ == 0) {
            spaces_ = count_;
            completion_cb_();
            generation_++;
        } else {
            while (generation_ == my_generation);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
  int64_t x = 0;
  const int kNumThreads = 4;
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  SpinningBarrier barrier(kNumThreads, [&]{
    // On completion, the last thread will increment x and log the message.
    x += 1;
    if (x % (1024 * 1024) == 0) {
      auto elapsed = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - begin;
      auto micros = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed).count() + 1;
      std::cerr << x * 1000000 / micros << " completions / second\n";
    }
  });
  std::vector<std::jthread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < kNumThreads; ++i) {
    threads.push_back(std::jthread([&] {
      while(true) {
        barrier.Wait();
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: i recall amd having 2 chips on the CPU containing 8 cores each, so if one core is on the other chip you will have chip-to-chip communication, but i cannot get any sources on this, you'll have to get an AMD employee to confirm this.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Thanks! I found this: https://www.anandtech.com/show/17585/amd-zen-4-ryzen-9-7950x-and-ryzen-5-7600x-review-retaking-the-high-end/10
This article confirms your claim and shows that core-to-core latencies are significantly higher between the lower 8 cores and higher 8 cores.

Comment: Btw each core complex (CCX, 8 core) has its own L3, so it's not entirely shared.

Comment: https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/08/amds-zen-4-part-2-memory-subsystem-and-conclusion/ doesn't discuss much about inter-core latency or bandwidth (mostly about memory bandwidth and latency to various levels of cache for each core separately), but the DRAM bandwidth section does show the topology of 2 CCDs (core cluster dies) connected by an IO die.  Also https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_4#Memory_Hierarchy .  Zen 1 had 4-core CCXs, see diagrams in https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen#Single.2FMulti-chip_Packages